# nhibernate foreign key relationship on between two natual key columns

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-interface

I want to define foreign key relationship between two tables using natural keys... By default nhibernate is considering the other column as primary key...

```
Class A{
   public virtual int id {get; set;}
   public virtual int username {get; set;}
}

Class B{
   public virtual int id {get; set;}
   public virtual int username {get; set;}
}
```

I want to define foreign key relation from class B (col: username) on class A (col:username)

```
ManyToOne<ClassA>( x=> x.ClassA, map => { map.Column("username"); };
```

Nhibenate is creating it on username to id and not on username to username.. how can i achieve this?

Thanks, mayur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look at the link: [NHibernate - Mapping a String Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462281/nhibernate-mapping-a-string-foreign-key)

you need to use the property-ref tag in key section and specify the name of the column which is unique in other table.

```
<bag name=”Inventory” table=”INVENTORY” lazy=”true”>
 <key column=”ID” property-ref=”OID” />
 <one-to-many class=”GuitarStore.Common.Inventory” />
 </bag>
```