# NHibernate generate DB script not referencing column when adding a constraint

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, ddl

I have an nhibernate xml class (called class1) with the following property:

```
<many-to-one name="Rank" class="RankColourScheme" column="Rank_" 
property-ref="Rank" not-null="true" fetch="join"/>
```

The column Rank_ is not the primary key column.

When I use nhibernate to generate the sql script to create the tables, the SQL line is:

```
alter table dbo.Class1_  add constraint FK_Rank foreign key (Rank_) 
references dbo.RankColourScheme_
```

This line fails, because the constraint isn't referencing the column.

The actual sql should be:

```
alter table dbo.Class1_  add constraint FK_Rank foreign key (Rank_) 
references dbo.RankColourScheme_ (Rank_)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong with my xml?

Thanks in advance,

Nadia

Comment: That must be something different, because it is not necessary to reference the PK column explicitely: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8839/2

Answer (score 1):

have a look at : [NHibernate - Mapping a String Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462281/nhibernate-mapping-a-string-foreign-key)

you need to define it as:

```
<bag name=”Inventory” table=”INVENTORY” lazy=”true”>
 <key column=”ID” property-ref=”OID” />
 <one-to-many class=”GuitarStore.Common.Inventory” />
 </bag>
```

also this was intially but in nhibernate https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1272, and it is fixed in 2.1.0Alpha1.